# WPF Canvas Button?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, button

I'm learning WPF at the moment.

I have a vector graphics canvas that I'd like to use as the background for a button, but I can't seem to find a way to do this in the documentation.  I thought this would be an obvious thing to want to do.

Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a VisualBrush :

```
<Button Content="Hello">
    <Button.Background>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <!-- Your vector graphics here -->
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  DrawingBrush didn't work - I have a canvas in a resource, and it didn't seem to like a canvas, whereas a VisualBrush does.

Answer (score 3):

Apologies,

I think I've found the solution.  [DrawingBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingbrush.aspx).

Thanks,
Mark